# Python Dataframe: Split a value in a row to multiple rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df with two columns `col1` and `col2`. I'm trying to split if there is any comma seperated values.
For ex: From `1,2 - mason` to `1 - mason` and `2 - mason`

df

```
    df= pd.DataFrame(data = {'col1' : ['1,2', '2', '3', '4', '5,6,7,8'], 'col2' : ['mason', 'marcus', 'anthony', 'paul', 'bruno']}) 


        col1    col2
    0   1,2     mason
    1   2       marcus
    2   3       anthony
    3   4       paul
    4   5,6,7,8 bruno
```

My excepted output:

```
        col1    col2
    0   1       mason
    1   2       mason   
    2   2       marcus
    3   3       anthony
    4   4       paul
    5   5       bruno
    6   6       bruno
    7   7       bruno
    8   8       bruno
    9   9       bruno
```

Comment: `df.assign(col1=df['col1'].str.split(',')).explode('col1').reset_index(drop=True)` ?

Comment: `df = df.assign(col1=df['col1'].str.split(','))` , then check the duplicate link mentionded